Can't get a user IP address in nginx proxy
I have the following nginx configuration in docker. The problem is in my node app (backend proxy) I get an IP of nginx server, not the user real IP when sending requests from frontend using X-Real-IP headers or X-Forwarder-For
upstream frontend {
    server frontend:3000;
}

upstream backend {
    server backend:4000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    location / {
        auth_basic "Restricted";
        auth_basic_user_file  /etc/nginx/.htpasswd;

        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        proxy_read_timeout 1m;
        proxy_connect_timeout 1m;
        proxy_pass http://frontend;
    }

    location /api {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;

        rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break;
        proxy_pass http://backend;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        proxy_pass http://backend;

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }
}


Capture HTTP packets in and out and then use a tool like Wireshark to analyze the headers.

You are most probably use a bridge network, which is default for docker networking. AFAIK, for being able to get the real remote client address, you need to use either host or macvlan network for your docker container. Or you can run nginx directly on your host, dockerizing only the backend app(s).

Instead of using the rewrite /api/(.*) /$1 break; directive, a more efficient way would be to strip the /api prefix using the URI part on the backend proxy_pass argument: location /api/ { ... proxy_pass http://backend/; ... } (note the location prefix change and the trailing slash after backend).
